# Magento2.1.5 How can i add multipul custom fields on customer registration form(admin panel)

Tags: magento-2.0

I have added the single field in the customer registration form in admin end.

But i want to add the one more (multipul fields ).This is my code .

```
      $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'Company_name', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Company Name tst3',
        'input' => 'text',           
        'required' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,
        'system' => 0,

    ]);       
    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'Company_name')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create'],
    ]);
```

This is the code for addded single fields and it is working fine .
Now I am trying the code for add one more field.

```
     $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'Company_name', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Company Name tst3',
        'input' => 'text',           
        'required' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,
        'system' => 0,

    ],'Admin_email', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Admin Email',
        'input' => 'input',
        'required' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,           
    ]);       
    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'Company_name','Admin_email')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create'],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can go at it by putting the desired attributes in an array like so

```
$attributesInfo = [
        'attribut1' => [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Company Name tst3',
            'input' => 'text',           
            'required' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ],
        'attribut2' => [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Admin Email',
            'input' => 'text',           
            'required' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ],
    ];

foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }
```

and then the other part involving eav

```
$companyAttribute= $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute1');
    $companyAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['handle1','handle2'],
    ]);
$adminEmailAttribute= $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute2');
    $adminEmailAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['handle1','handle2'],
    ]);
```

here's a decent tutorial (2.1 or higher)

http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-1-3-how-to-make-customer-attribute-update.html

should've asked in magento.stackexchange